# Sessão em PHP utilizando classe

Tags: php, session

Olá, sou novo no PHP e gostaria de saber se tem como criar uma classe para gerenciar a sessão do usuário.

Seria uma função para iniciar a sessão e outra para destruir a sessão.

Se tiver como criar, como eu poderia estar fazendo isso ?

Comment: Que tal usar sem uma classe? Que ganhos espera ter criando uma classe?

Comment: @bigown de quase todas as inconsistências do PHP, colocarem OOP está cada vez mais me parecendo uma das piores. Agora ninguém mais quer saber de aprender PHP de verdade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer uma classe que tem a função de iniciar e destruir uma sessão, então ai tá um breve exemplo

```
class Session {
    public static function init() {
        if(session_id() == '') {
            session_start();
        }
    }

    public static function destroy() {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @lai0n era isso mesmo o que eu estava querendo saber, se tinha como criar uma classe para gerenciar isso, pois criar arquivos separados não me pareceu a melhor opção.